# getting a nameerror in python. while two other name is working, one name is not working..!

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python; if I write this code it shows:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/ultimate tym remaining.py", line 37, in <module>
    print("so the reamining time is %d hour, %d minutes and %d seconds" %(hr,minr,sr))
 NameError: name 'minr' is not defined
```

My code was:

```
hg=12
mg=00
sg=00
hn=10
mn=47
sn=49

if(mg>mn & hg>hn):
    hr=hn+24-hn-1
elif(mg<mn & hg>hn):
    hr=hn+24-hg
elif(mg>mn & hg<hn):
    hr=hn-hg-1
elif(mg<mn & hg<hn):
    hr=hn-hg
elif(hg==hn):
    hr=0

if(sg<sn & mg>mn):
    minr=mn+60-mg
elif(sg<sn & mg<mn):
    minr= mn-mg
elif(sg>sn & mg>mn):
    minr=mn+60-mg-1
elif(sg>sn & mg<mn):
    minr=mn-mg-1
elif(mg==mn):
    minr=0

if(sg>sn):
    sr=sn+60-sg
elif(sg<sn):
    sr=sn-sg
elif(sf==ss):
    sr=0

print("so the reamining time is %d hour, %d minutes and %d seconds" %(hr,minr,sr))
```

Why is this happening? Why are `hr` and `sr` working and `minr` is not?

Comment: Python's logical AND operator is `and`, not `&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following `if` construct is defining `minr`:

```
if(sg<sn & mg>mn):
    minr=mn+60-mg
elif(sg<sn & mg<mn):
    minr= mn-mg
elif(sg>sn & mg>mn):
    minr=mn+60-mg-1
elif(sg>sn & mg<mn):
    minr=mn-mg-1
elif(mg==mn):
    minr=0
```

What's happening is simple:  None of the conditions happens to be `True`, leaving `minr` undefined.  This can even happen after fixing the logical AND operator – it's `and`, not `&`, as pointed out by Amber.  `sg == sn` might hold, while `mg != mn`.

Comment: thnks, i was actually making a mistake in writing and as &. i know c a lil bit. and that actually led to this embarrasment!